# How to connect two express.js servers with socket.io?

Tags: express, socket.io

I try connect express.js servers. One server is backend, other is judge system - for compile tasks. after checking every test judge system send result. Because I only save this first server. For example:

```
app.post('/submit', async (req,res)=>{
    const {solution, language, problemId} = req.body
    const tests = await Tests.find({problem: problemId})
    const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:4001', {solution, language, tests})
})
```

But this only get full result.

```
judge.post('/', async (req,res)=>{
    const {solution, language, tests} = req.body
    tests.forEach(async test=>{
         const result = await check(solution, language, test.input, test.output) // send to compile and get result
       // at here I want to add socket.io for send information
       // for example
       // socket.emit('compile', {problemId: el.problem, result}) 
    })
    const tests = await Tests.find({problem: problemId})
    const result = await axios.post('http://localhost:4001', {solution, language, tests})
})
```

First server I want to this

```
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();

const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer);

io.on('connection', async (socket)=>{
    console.log("connected")
    socket.on('compile', ({problemId, result})=>{
    // save here
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', async ()=>{
        
        console.log('cykdym')
    })
})
```

But it is dont work. How to do this? Help me please.
Problem here not use socket.io. How to connect this? After one test I want to save this.